# Tumbling Window trigger in Azure Data Factory - Self Run

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-data-factory

I have a got an ADF V2 Pipeline that runs hourly between 7am and 5pm only. So far I have been using an "Event" trigger that runs hourly and it was fine.
But somehow the load started to run for more than one hour.
As a result, the next load would start while the previous one was still running.

I have been trying to use a "Tumbling Window" trigger to create a self dependency on this pipeline so that it waits for the previous one to be completed before running but could not make it work.

If someone has some experience about how to tackle this problem, any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: If answer is helpful, accept the answer as it is beneficial to other community members

Answer (score 1):

Max Concurrency property can be used in tumbling window triggers where if it is set to 1 it will not let the other instance of trigger to be initiated until the other one completes.

[Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-tumbling-window-trigger#tumbling-window-trigger-type-properties) can be referred for the details

[image]